# Find cell content and replace the second occurrence

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

'Im catching keywords (string) from an excel file and searching for them in a word doc. When found the string in the doc file is replaced with a specific content from an offset cell.This works for me .Some of the cells have multiple texts separated with semicolon ";".Each text must replace an occurrence of the found keyword in the doc file: for example if a cell contains 3 strings separated with a semicolon ,the first string should replace the first occurrence of the keyword in the doc file,the second one the second occurrence and the third one the third occurrence. I couldn't get a correct result. Below is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub copy_file(source, destination)
Dim FsyObjekt As Object
Set FsyObjekt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FsyObjekt.CopyFile source, destination
End Sub

Public Sub WordFindAndReplace(Index_offset, ProdType)
Dim ws As Worksheet, msWord As Object, itm As Range
Dim spl() As String, NbLines, Index, Occurences As Integer



Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Index = 0

With msWord
    .Visible = True
    .Documents.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template.docx"
    .Activate
    
    With .ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                    
        For Each itm In ws.Range("A6:A221")
        
            .Text = itm.Text
                If IsEmpty(itm.Offset(, Index_offset)) Then
                    .Replacement.Text = "  "
                Else
                    
                    If InStr(1, itm.Offset(, Index_offset), ";", 1) > 0 Then
                            .Forward = True
                            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                            .Format = False
                            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
                            
                            spl = Split((itm.Offset(, Index_offset)), ";")
                            
                            NbLines = UBound(spl) - LBound(spl) + 1
                            Index = 0
                            
                                If Index <> NbLines - 1 Then
                                    .Replacement.Text = spl(Index)
                                    Index = Index + 1
                                End If
                            
                     Else
                            
                            
                         .Replacement.Text = itm.Offset(, Index_offset).Text
                         .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
                            
                     End If
                                                      
                End If
                
            
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .Replacement.Highlight = False
            
             
        Next itm
    End With
    
    .Quit SaveChanges:=True
    

End With

    
End Sub
```

I hope someone could help me to solve the problem.

Comment: If there's only a single value in the cell should it replace all instances?  If there are more instances in the Word doc than the number of values in the cell what should happen with the remaining replacements?

Comment: Yes,if there is only a value in the cell it should replace all found instances.for the second question , normaly i should delete the remaining replacements if there are more instances in the doc word than the number of values in the cell.

Comment: Could you edit your question with quick examples? I’m confused by your rules for the replacements

Comment: If there is only one value in the cell and the cell doesnt contain a ";" then all found instances should be replaced with this value. If the cell contains strings separated with ";" then each of those strings should replace orderly the found instances.  If there are more instances in the Word doc than the number of values in the cell  for example  in the cell {Aaaa;Bbbb;Cccc} and in the word doc 5 instances of the keyword "ProdName" then only the first 3 instances will be replaced and the others deleted from the word file(replaced with an empty string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you pass in 'ProdType' isn't used in the code you have published.

I've updated the code you published and it compiles, but obviously I can't run it because I don't have your worksheet and documents.

But it will help point you in the right direction

A key thing to note is how the search and replace operations have been split out from your main loop.  This make the code much easier to follow.

Good luck with your endeavors.

```
Public Sub WordFindAndReplace(Index_Offset As Long, ProdType As String)  ' ProdType is not used in the code you published

Const blankString                   As String = "  "            ' might bebetter using vbnullstring instead of "  "

Dim ws                              As Excel.Worksheet          ' Requires that Tools.References.Microsoft Excel X.XX Object Library is ticked
Dim msWord                          As Word.Application         ' Requires that Tools.References.Microsoft Word X.XX Object Library is ticked
Dim spl()                           As String                   '  changed back to string as we can also iterate over a string array
Dim mySpl                           As Variant                  ' the variable in a for each has to be an object or variant
Dim myIndex                         As Long                     ' Was implicitly declared as Variant
Dim myDoc                           As Word.Document            ' Better to get a specific reference to a document rather than use activedocument
Dim myOffsetString                  As String
Dim myFindString                    As String               '
Dim myCells()                       As Variant
Dim myOffsetCells                   As Variant
Dim myOffsetRange                   As Variant

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set msWord = New Word.Application ' changed from late to early binding as early binding gives intelisense for word objects
    'Index = 0 not needed any more

    With msWord
        .Visible = True                 ' Not necessary if you just want to process some actions on a document but helpful when developing
        Set myDoc = .Documents.Open(FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template.docx") 'changed to function form due to assignment to myDoc
        '.Activate  ' Not needed when working with a direct reference to a document
    End With

    ' Bring the cells in the target column and the offset column into vba arrays
    ' an idiosyncracy when pullin in a column is we get a two dimensional array
    myCells = ws.Range("A6:A221").Value2
    myOffsetRange = Replace("A6:A221", "A", Chr$(Asc("A") + Index_Offset))
    myOffsetCells = ws.Range(myOffsetRange).Value2
    ' As we are using two arrays we can't now do for each so back to using an index
    ' Another idiosyncracy is that the arrays start at 1 and not 0
    For myIndex = 1 To UBound(myCells)

        myOffsetString = CStr(myOffsetCells(myIndex, 1))
        myFindString = CStr(myCells(myIndex, 1))

        If Len(myOffsetString) = 0 Then                                'quicker than comparing against vbnullstring
            replaceText_ReplaceAll myDoc, myFindString, blankString

        Else
            ' The offset cell contains a string (because it is not empty)
            ' It doesn't matter if there is no ';' in the string
            ' split will just produce an array with one cell

            spl = Split(myOffsetString, ";")

            If UBound(spl) = 0 Then
                ' Only one item present
                replaceText_ReplaceAll myDoc, myFindString, Trim(CStr(mySpl))
            Else
                ' more than one item present
                For Each mySpl In spl
                    replaceText_ReplaceSingleInstance myDoc, myFindString, Trim(CStr(mySpl))

                Next

                ' now replace any excess ocurrences of myFIndString
                replaceText_ReplaceAll myDoc, myFindString, blankString
            End If
        End If

    Next

    myDoc.Close savechanges:=True
    msWord.Quit
    Set msWord = Nothing

End Sub

    Sub replaceText_ReplaceAll(this_document As Word.Document, findText As String, replaceText As String)

        With this_document.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Format = False
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Text = findText
            .Replacement.Text = replaceText
            .Forward = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute

        End With

    End Sub

    Sub replaceText_ReplaceSingleInstance(this_document As Word.Document, findText As String, replaceText As String)

        With this_document.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Format = False
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Text = findText
            .Replacement.Text = replaceText
            .Forward = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute

        End With

    End Sub
```

Edited to update the WordFIndAndReplace sub

Comment: thanks for the Help but i got ByRef argument type mismatch error for both 'myFindString' and 'myOffsetString' variables :/

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've had another look tweaked the code and run it in an excel workbook and it seems to be ok.  I've edited by answer to include the updated code.

The code should be run from within an excel.workbook module.

Comment: Thanks Steven! it worked for me but with some modifications: .Execute Replace for both replacement subs and if one item is present i used the spl(0) as argument to the replaceText_ReplaceAll Sub.

Comment: Great news. I'M glad you were able to modify things to your needs.